# Way to get graphics tablet TRUST TB-6300 working in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: graphics, tablet, wacom

I was hoping last updates will bring this (quite old) tablet back to use but so far they aren't. When tablet is plugged into USB it just blinks green led and nothing happens. If there is a way to make it work please share your experience. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the way that finally worked in my case.
I've downloaded deb-files of libwacom [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/amd64/libwacom2/download) and libwacom-common [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/all/libwacom-common/download)

To the date of this post most actual versions were:

> libwacom2_0.22-1_amd64.deb
>
> libwacom-common_0.22-1_all.deb

Below is connected to above versions so make sure you download and replace with actual names.

I've installed packages with:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i libwacom2_0.22-1_amd64.deb libwacom-common_0.22-1_all.deb
```

Then I've included following repository and installed package:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:doctormo/wacom-plus
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
$ sudo apt-get install wacom-dkms
```

Upon reboot my graphics tablet works as it should. Thanks Age of Asparagus for giving great hint!